# Net Maui Issue Picker Inside a frame

Tags: c#, .net, maui, frame, maui-windows

I am building a Maui App and i have noticed that on Windows , when i wrap a picker inside a Frame element , the selected item disappears.
Has anyone encountered the same issue and found a workaround ? or am i doing somenthing wrong?

I have created a very simple example , the upper picker works properly , while the 2nd is showing this issue.
https://streamable.com/vm8vip

```
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="*,*">

        <Picker
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="Monkey"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            FontAttributes="Bold">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>


        <Frame
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Picker 
                x:Name="MonkeyFrame"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                TextColor="White"
                FontAttributes="Bold" >
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </Frame>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Remove the frame. Way too many bugs. Use border instead.

Comment: `Frame` is a legacy view, kept for compatibility with Xamarin.Forms. It doesn't use the new Maui rendering framework. As H.A.H. mentions, `Border` is recommended instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The video of [link](https://streamable.com/v16niw) that you provided is not available.

Comment: thank you for suggessting to use the border ! indeed i don't have any issue using that , i have reuploaded the video

Answer (score 0):

> when i wrap a picker inside a Frame element , the selected item disappears.

I tested the code you provided and found that you set `TextColor` of the second picker to "White". I set it to "Black" then it will work well...

**Update:**

For Windows, I found that whether it's Frame or Border or not, the color of selected item always turns default colors(Black or white) instead of disappearing.
You can raise an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) for it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i have tryed setting the texocolor to black as you suggested , and i am experiencing the same kind of issue, it doesn't seems to make any change

Comment: I saw the video you provided and tested it. I found that whether it's `Frame` or `Border` or not, the color of selected item always turns Black instead of disappearing. This is really outrageous...

Comment: You can set `TextColor` of the first picker to "Red" to test it.